# problems when trying to compile groovy class inside a java class

Tags: java, grails, groovy

We currently need to migrate an application from Grails 2.x to Grails 3.x

We do not know much about this application but in the past, in v2, it used Groovy classes inside Java classes.

After upgrading to v3, this doesn't seem to work anymore. Having Groovy code inside a Java class will return this

```
...: error: cannot find symbol
      line of code with the error
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable MyGroovyClass
  location: class MyJavaClass


MyJavaClass

public class MyJavaClass {
  public void x() { MyGroovyClass.test(); }
}

MyGroovyClass

class MyGroovyClass {
  static void test() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Too few information to help you. What is your question?

Comment: @daggett added a few lines of code. don't think it is very useful since this is all I have. In grails 2 this code worked, in grails 3, not anymore

Comment: Seems Java compiled before groovy. Check compilation steps and plugins. What if you change Java to groovy extension? BTW, what are the file locations?

Comment: @daggett they are placed under src/main/java and src/main/groovy. changing extension won't fix the problem because in the Groovy files we there are some specific groovy annotations

Comment: @daggett "What if you change Java to groovy extension?" - That is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they are placed under src/main/java and src/main/groovy

The simple thing to do, and the thing that most Grails apps do, is put all of the Java and Groovy source code under `src/main/groovy/`.  That allows the Groovy joint compiler to compile all of it together as a single unit so you can have bidirectional dependencies between the Groovy and Java classes.  It is possible to configure support for separate directories but it involves some complexity that doesn't really buy you anything, which is why the convention is to use `src/main/groovy`/.

Comment: This solution worked and is pretty quick. Not really the right one but for the moment I can work it out using this.

Comment: "Not really the right one but for the moment I can work it out using this." - I am glad you got it working.  The reason that we have `grails create-app` create `src/main/groovy/` and not `src/main/java/` is the preferred convention is to do that.

Comment: The issue is with the default build config, `src/main/groovy/` and `src/main/java/` are compiles separately which means one has to be compiled first which means that one cannot have references to the other one, because it isn't compiled yet.  Putting it all in `src/main/groovy/` allows it all to be compiled together. Groovy provides a joint compiler which allows Groovy and Java sources to be compiled as 1 unit, allowing bidirectional dependencies.

Comment: An alternative is to add `src/main/java/` to the `sourceSets` for `compileGroovy` so those sources will be compiled at the same time as the sources under `src/main/groovy/`.  If you do that, it can be made to work, but is more build config since you are deviating from the defaults, and is a non-standard thing.